# Программно не создаются TextView в LinearLayout в методе OnCreate

Tags: android, android-textview, android-linearlayout

Пытаюсь высчитать при открытии Layout величину экрана и создать на нем соответствующее количество цветных полосок высотой 100dp , использую тот же метод для порождения полосок, что и при скроллинге, но при скроллинге полоски порождаются и все хорошо, а при открытии в отладчике пишет, что у LinearLayout нужное количество Children, но на экране их нет

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    svContent = (ExtraScrollView) findViewById(R.id.svScroll);
    svContent.setOnScrollChanged(new ExtraScrollView.ScrollViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged(ExtraScrollView scrollView, int x, int y,
                                    int oldx, int oldy) {
            // когда прокрутили почти до конца вниз
            if (y + scrollView.getExtentVertical() >= scrollView
                    .getChildHeight() - 10) {
                //  подгружаем данные
                textViewGeneration();
            }
        }
    });
    //этот метод и не хочет работать
    InitialColorStrips();
}

public void InitialColorStrips() {
    //получим высоту экрана
    Point size = new Point();
    WindowManager w = getWindowManager();
    w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
    int mWindowHeight = size.y;

    for (int i=0; i < mWindowHeight/100 + 2; i++) {
        textViewGeneration();
    }
}

public void textViewGeneration() {
    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lpView = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(l.getWidth(), 100);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lpView);

    hue+=1;
    int parsedColor = Color.HSVToColor(new float[]{ hue, 100f, 100f } );
    tv.setBackgroundColor(parsedColor);

    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AdditionalActivity.class);
            // указываем первым параметром ключ, а второе значение
            // по ключу мы будем получать значение с Intent
            intent.putExtra("color", Color.HSVToColor(new float[]{ hue, 100f, 100f } ));

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    l.addView(tv);
}
```

разметка такая:

```
<ru.surf.victoria_sokolova.ExtraScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/svScroll">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</ru.surf.victoria_sokolova.ExtraScrollView>
```

приложение не падает, но выводит такое

[image]

при скроллинге тем же методом все начинает работать

[image]

а хотелось бы получить такое:

[image]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что на момент вызова `onCreate`, элементы интерфейса еще не отрисованы. Поэтому `getWidth()` возвращает 0. Рекомендую вместо `getWidth()` использовать `match_parent`

Comment: Безумно благодарна! Догадывалась, что раз в отладке элементы есть, то беда с отрисовкой, но не видела эту проблему, все починилось!